# Why is Spring @Configuration class inheritance not working as expected?

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, dependency-injection, component-scan

I have an abstract Spring configuration class that includes a common bean:

```
public abstract class AbstractConfig {
    @Bean
    public CommonBean commonBean {
        CommonBean commonBean = new CommonBean();
        commonBean.specifics = getSpecifics();
    };

    public abstract String getSpecifics();
}
```

The common bean's specifics are set by its subclasses:

```
package realPackage;
@Configuration
public class RealConfig extends AbstractConfig {
    @Override
    public String getSpecifics() {
        return "real";
    }
}
```

...and...

```
package testPackage;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"testPackage", "realPackage" })
public class TestConfig extends AbstractConfig {
    @Override
    public String getSpecifics() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

My test only needs to use the `TestConfig` and shouldn't know about the `RealConfig` (but does need access to other components in `realPackage`). It begins:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class MyIntegrationTestIT { //... }
```

With the code above, this works as expected and uses the `"test"` specifics. But if I reverse the order of packages in the `@ComponentScan`, the `"real"` specifics are used instead. This is baffling me - am specifying the `TestConfig` so surely it should be calling the overridden method on this? Could anyone advise as to the reasons Spring does this and how it might be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be due to a lack of understanding on my part of how beans annotated with `@Configuration` are picked up by a component scan.

Comment: thanks. would appreciate a little more elaboration in this specific context.

Comment: Since @Configuration is meta annotated with @Component, it too becomes eligible for component scanning and gets picked up. Therefore the `RealConfig` configuration bean gets picked up by the component scan on `TestConfig` class. More information can be found in the Spring framework docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.26.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-configuration-annotation

Answer (score 1):

Your current example will most likely not compile. AbstractConfig should look like this code snippet, but I assume this is only a copy/paste error.

```
public abstract class AbstractConfig {
    @Bean
    public CommonBean commonBean() {
        CommonBean commonBean = new CommonBean();
        commonBean.specifics = getSpecifics();
        return commonBean;
    }

    public abstract String getSpecifics();
}
```

The feature you are looking for is the @Profile annotation (see https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile for more details). You need to change your code as follows

RealConfig

```
package realPackage;
@Configuration
@Profile("real")
public class RealConfig extends AbstractConfig {
...
```

TestConfig

```
package testPackage;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"testPackage", "realPackage" })
@Profile("test")
public class TestConfig extends AbstractConfig {
```

MyIntegrationTestIT

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyIntegrationTestIT {
...
```